# Pagination Last link disappeard after page 10

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, pagination

I make a pagination with Pagination Class of CodeIgniter and some tutorials, it work fine, but the problem is that after the page number 10 do not show the **Last Page** link.
**My controller**

```
  $select_per_page = 5;
  if ($this->session->userdata('cantidad')) {
      $select_per_page = $this->session->userdata('cantidad');
    }
  $obj = new General();

// (BEGIN) Pagination//

$config['base_url'] = base_url('test/Gestionar_Test/'); 
$config['per_page'] = $select_per_page;
$config['num_links'] = 4;
$config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get('normas')->num_rows();
$inicio = $this->uri->segment(3);

$data['query'] = $query_lista_norma = $obj->Searcher_Norma($select_per_page, $inicio);

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
// (END) Pagination//

 $data['pagination_view'] = 'contents/General_Content/pagination_view'; 
 $data['contents'] = 'contents/test';
 $this->load->view('template', $data);
```

**My view**

```
<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<div><?php echo $row->norma; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

// Then I show the pagination links

```
<?php
  foreach ($links as $link) {
?>
<li>
  <?php echo $link ?>
</li>
<?php
   } 
?>
```

I have 26 pages in total, all shows OK, but in the page **11**, and in the next one until 26 does not show the **Last link**

Thank´s in advance.