# how to use where clause in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

When I click the 2nd page link of the CodeIgniter pagination it will root 2nd page and shows the data, but the pagination link automatically removed. Could you please help me find my mistake?

My view:

```
  <?php
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    echo $row->id"<br>";
}
echo $this
    ->pagination
    ->create_links();
?>
```

My Controller:

```
public function search()
{

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $list= $this->input->post('list');
    $category=$this->input->post('category');
    $area=$this->input->post('area');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/Main_control/search";
    $this->db->where('subcategory',$category);        
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('ad_listing')->num_rows();
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config["per_page"] = 3;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    if( !$data["results"] = $this->Main_model->fetch_countries($category,$config["per_page"], $page))
    {
        echo "error";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view("test",$data);
    } 
}
```

My model:

```
public function fetch_countries($category,$limit, $start) {

        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("ad_listing");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: please any one help me ..

Comment: give people a chance.  You posted the question 4 minutes ago and added your comment 3 minutes ago.

Comment: in your model, you have a `$category` and you do not use it, and in the controller you have a `where` and I o not know why yo use it

Comment: you can see this post and maybe can help you, **it works for me !!!**     [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419996/pagination-last-link-disappeard-after-page-10)

Comment: tell me if this help you

Comment: i want particular  data that  why i use the where clause, but where clause work only the first page .

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: why you do not put the `where`clause in your model?

Comment: yes i got the answer . thank you for all ,for supporting me

Answer (score 0):

In your **model** you have to add

```
public function fetch_countries($category,$limit, $start) {

    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```

> $this->db->where('subcategory',$category);

```
    $query = $this->db->get("ad_listing");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```